# One mysqli works and another not..?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code for pulling out ALL users from database.
This code works, and shows all the users from DB

```
<?php

$sqlsel = "SELECT picture,username,email,configured,gender FROM members ORDER BY username";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sqlsel);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($profpicture,$uname,$email,$confred,$gender);
while($stmt->fetch())
{
    if(empty($profpicture)){
    echo "<img src='profile_pictures/public_icon.png' width='50' height='50'><br>";}else {
                                        echo " <div class='img'><img  src='profile_pictures/".$profpicture."' alt='Profile Pic'></div><br>";
                                }
    echo "<b>Email:</b> ".$email."<br> ";

    if($gender == Woman){
        $gen = her;
    }
    else{
        $gen = his;
    }

      echo "<b>Username: </b>".$uname." </p> ";
if(empty($confred)){
    echo "<font color='#FF4747'>".$uname." has not configured ".$gen." account yet.</font>";
} else{
    echo "<form action='".$uname.".php'>
        <input type='submit' class='buttondiv' value='Visit ".$uname."&apos;s Profile'>
</form>";
}
    echo "<hr class='hr' />";

} 
?>
```

And so I did almost the same, but with posts. It should pull out all posts from database, but it shows only the first one... Why?

```
<?php

$selectposts = "SELECT postby,posttxt,time FROM posts ORDER BY time";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($selectposts);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($postby,$posttxt,$posttime);
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $stmt->close();
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT picture FROM members WHERE username = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $postby);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($picture);
                        while ($stmt->fetch()){
                                if(empty($picture)){
                                        $profpicturefromdb = " <img src='profile_pictures/public_icon.png' width='25' height='25' class='fxdmimg'>";
                                } else {
                                        $profpicturefromdb = " <img width='25' class='fxdmimg' height='25' src='profile_pictures/".$picture."' alt='Profile Picture'>";
                             }
echo 
"<p><center><div class='postdv'> 
<b>".$profpicturefromdb." 
<h3>".$postby."</h3></b><font color='#000'>  
[ ".$posttime." ]</font><hr class='hr'>
<font color='#000'>".$posttxt."</font><hr class='hr'>
<form method='POST'>
<input type='submit' name='voteup' class='voteup' value='Up'> 
<input type='submit' name='votedown' class='votedown' value='Down'>
</form>
</center>
</div>";
}
}

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: You close your statement inside the for loop, so you can make your second query. When the first iteration is done, there's no more results because the query is closed. To fix this, rename the variable you're using for the inner SQL query to something other that `$stmt`

Comment: Don't run queries in a loop. Rewrite your orighinal query to retrieve the data you need in one query.

Comment: Makes sense, I voted up for your answers but now I got call to a member function bind_param...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you rewrite first query results in $stmt variable. Try this one:

```
<?php

$selectposts = "SELECT postby,posttxt,time FROM posts ORDER BY time";
$stmt        = $mysqli->prepare($selectposts);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($postby, $posttxt, $posttime);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT picture FROM members WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt1->bind_param('s', $postby);
    $stmt1->execute();
    $stmt1->bind_result($picture);
    while ($stmt1->fetch()) {
        if (empty($picture)) {
            $profpicturefromdb = " <img src='profile_pictures/public_icon.png' width='25' height='25' class='fxdmimg'>";
        } else {
            $profpicturefromdb = " <img width='25' class='fxdmimg' height='25' src='profile_pictures/" . $picture . "' alt='Profile Picture'>";
        }
        echo "<p><center><div class='postdv'>
            <b>" . $profpicturefromdb . "
            <h3>" . $postby . "</h3></b><font color='#000'>
            [ " . $posttime . " ]</font><hr class='hr'>
            <font color='#000'>" . $posttxt . "</font><hr class='hr'>
            <form method='POST'>
            <input type='submit' name='voteup' class='voteup' value='Up'>
            <input type='submit' name='votedown' class='votedown' value='Down'>
            </form>
            </center>
            </div>";
    }
}
$stmt->close();

?>
```

Comment: It makes sense, but now, I got call to a member function bind_param at stmt1->bind_param('s',$postby);

Comment: $stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare // here is assignment, so $stmt1 is declared, or not this you asked?

Comment: Well, I solved it by moving the call for picture at the top of code , so it does not have to be in the while stmt... Anyway, thanks for your answer, I'm making it the best one.

Comment: As a suggestion: make inner join, so then you will have only one query :)